# Why wikipedia says this Riemann integrability definition is "very difficult to use"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-integration

There are "plenty" of definition of Riemann integrability for a real function. For example:

1. $\forall \epsilon>0,~\exists \delta >0$, $\forall P$: partition of
   $[a,b]$, $\forall T$: sample points of $P$, ($\lVert
   P\rVert<\delta\Rightarrow |S(f,P,T)-I|<\epsilon$).
2. $\forall \epsilon>0,~\exists P$: partition of
   $[a,b]$, $\forall P'$: refinement of $P$, $\forall T$: sample points of $P'$, $|S(f,P,T)-I|<\epsilon$.
3. ...

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) said, the first criterion is "very difficult to use". However, I've seen many books didn't even mention the second criterion, just stating the first with Darboux integral(i.e. $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$ or "upper integral=lower integral"), or stating the first with Cauchy-criterion(i.e., when the mesh is small enough, the two Riemann Sum are very closed to each other). Why does wiki say so? Concrete examples that can point out why the second is more convenient are welcomed.

And on the other hand, I want to ask that, don't you think the second criterion is not very "free" and natural? Since it just guarantee the Riemann sum of all refinement of some fixed partition $P$ is closed to $I$, but if you have a partition that is not related to $P$, even its mesh is very very small, you can't conclude that its Riemann sum is closed to $I$. So doesn't the first criterion have better intution?

Comment: It's hard to deal with because it's a pain to work with a generic partition when all you know is the mesh fineness. If you have a bit of liberty to *choose* a partition (something finer, but more regularly spaced, for example), you might be able to get away without some of the technical difficulties.

Comment: If you have a partition $Q$ unrelated to $P$, then $Q$ has a refinement that is also a refinement of $P$.

Comment: @user296602 wow, reasonable! But can't such theorem be easily proved by Darboux integral or Cauchy criterion? I mean, if we encounter such situation, can we then turn into the way that using Darboux integral(aka. upper/lower sum language) or Cauchy-criterion?

Comment: @user296602 well, I want to ask are there such examples(theorems) that is hard to proved via the first criterion, but can be (somewhat) easily proved by the second one?

Comment: @Hurkyl I'm not so sure what you mean, can you explain more? :)

Comment: The second definition is more general but the distinction between two is more visible if one moves to Riemann-Stieltjes integration. And frankly speaking using the Riemann sum itself is painful because of the choice of tags. The simpler option is Darboux sums where we just need one partition to prove our point. Cauchy criterion is not popular (with very few books even discussing it) and I haven't seen it being used to prove many results.

Comment: Regarding @Hurkyl point just have a look at partition $P\cup Q$. This is a refinement of $P$ as well as of $Q$.